# REST API in Revel using mgo for Mongo - How to automatically add response parameters such as status and data?

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, go, revel

I'm using this implementation - https://github.com/sadhanandh/revelbasic - to build a customized REST API endpoint in Golang.

For any input parameter like, say, /brands, I have the following code -

Model:

```
func GetBrands(s *mgo.Session) []Brand {
    var results []Brand
    CollectionBrand(s).Find(bson.M{}).All(&results)
    return results
}
```

Controller:

```
func (c Book) Brands() revel.Result {
    b := models.GetBrands(c.MongoSession)
    return c.RenderJson(b)
}
```

The problem is that this gives a purely json response of the data with no server status codes.
I mean, the responses are like this -

```
[
{"data1"}, {"data2"}
]
```

Whereas what is actually expected is more like-

```
{
"apiversion": 123,
"status": "success",
"data": [{"data1"}, {"data2"}],
}
```

along with more information about the response such as a server status code, etc.

I can customize the response in my controller code to add these but shouldn't I be able to configure revel to do that automatically for every response?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in Revel (don't think it's possible, but maybe with an Interceptor), and I'm not familiar with revel basic, but I usually get that info from the HTTP response headers, rather than expecting it in the response body.

Comment: That's true, response headers are there but sometimes, let's say for a database operation, it is required to send the status of the operation whether it succeeded or not (response headers in both cases will show 200 OK)
Anyway, we moved to gorilla mux with a few middleware and things are good!